# .htaccess get var like a folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm new here and I need help with "transform" a `$_GET['var']` like folder

For example I have a website with languages, the url is like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=es&p=1
www.mywebsite.com/index.php?lang=en&p=1
```

then I want something like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com/EN/index.php?p=1
```

is like "transform" the `$_GET['var']` in that.

I don't have a directory with languages... then I need that whenever there is `lang = en` this change is made in the url
is this possible?
Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you know what languages your site can be displayed in, you can use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(en|se|fr|du)/(.*)$ $2?lang=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The QSA flag will append the current query string to the existing query string. The rest should be obvious.